# Highcharts paint zero axis black

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have a Highchart bar chart with negative values (with the bars then going downwards). Now I would like to paint a black line for y=0 like so: [image].

I haven't found a trivial way to do this and I would like to avoid directly modifing the SVG or adding a fake line chart or something. Maybe someone knows better way? I've already played around with `(minor)tickInterval` and `(minor)gridLineColor` but that wouldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  plot lines for this like shown in this example http://jsfiddle.net/4rpNU/

```
yAxis:{
 plotLines:{}
}
```

here is the api reference for it http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

Hope this will be useful for you :)

Comment: Wow, I totally missed out on this chapter in the documentation. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!